# Does passportjs handle user signup?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I scan the passportjs doc and don't find a user signup function. (Here I store user information in a self-host server.) Can passport handle that?

Comment: Thanks. Does it handle OAuth signup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passport.js – is a middleware, not complete application. So short answer is – no, passport.js does not perform complete signup process.
I believe there is no any other library could do this since your application has some unique code that performs actions usually called business logic or application logic or just simply logic.
But you can use passport.js to reduce amount of your code routinе. This is actually the general purpose which passport.js was used for. Probably the feature suitable for you is [password-local](http://passportjs.org/guide/username-password/).
There is well detailed tutorial for this feature http://danialk.github.io/blog/2013/02/23/authentication-using-passportjs/